# Javascript Dashboard Layout Framework

Tags: javascript, widget, dashboard

I've been looking at javascript frameworks that represent dashboards.  I'm actually trying to mimic the behavior of Atlassian's JIRA product with their dashboard.  As such, here are the requirements:

1. Columns layouts for the dashboard are pre-defined by the user ( 1col, 2col, 1col@30%-2ndCol@70% etc)
2. User can add widgets to the dashboard with an add button
3. User can drag widgets to a new location
4. When dragging, the widget takes on the width of the column it's being dragged to.
5. During dragging, displaced widgets are only moved up and down within their respective columns.

So far I've looked at [freewall](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/) and [gridster](http://gridster.net/). The problems with these frameworks are:

1. The widgets (aka cells) always retain their shape - I want the widget to take on the width of the column it's being dropped into (and btw, I'd like to alter its height during the drop event so that it's proportional)
2. The framework moves widgets across columns in an effort to fill up all space.

Does anyone know of javascript framework that comes a little closer to these requirements?

thx

Answer (score 3):

Wow, I've been looking for days and just found it!!

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/inettuts/

Comment: IGoogle interface is good option but it's not full supported in IE